# What is the best way to rename index in liquibase?

Tags: liquibase

What is the best way to rename index in liquibase? should I delete and recreate it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What db platform are you using?  Liquibase can do sql changeset that are allowed by the platform, so either should work.

Comment: @ronak SQL changeset is pretty useful thanks.

Answer (score 2):

At first, you must remove former index:

```xml
<changeSet id="20210905084713-2" author="ARMIN.NOROOZIAN">
    <dropIndex tableName="tpl_order" indexName="tracking_code_idx"/>
</changeSet>
```

Then create a new index:

```xml
<changeSet id="20210905084713-3" author="ARMIN.NOROOZIAN">
    <createIndex tableName="tpl_order" indexName="tpl_tracking_code_idx">
        <column name="tpl_tracking_code"/>
    </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```